# Why is the same package sometimes essential and not essential?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to reduce the hard disk footprint of my Debian Stretch installation by automatically `purge`ing all packages that are:

- not essential packages and
- not needed by any essential packages (possibly even indirectly).

An essential package is a package that has the `Essential` control field set.

For example, [init](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/init) is not an essential package, whereas [coreutils](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils) is essential.

I am currently confused if there are different definitions of essential.

When I use `dkpg`, I see that `init` is not essential:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Essential}\n' | grep init
init                                    no
init-system-helpers                     yes
initramfs-tools                         no
initramfs-tools-core                    no
sysvinit-utils                          yes
```

However, when removing `init` (which in and itself sounds like a bad idea, but that is not the point here) with `apt-get purge`, I get the message that `init` is indeed essential:

```
apt-get purge init
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  init*
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  init
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 19.5 kB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] n
Abort.
```

My questions are:

1. Why do `dkpg` and `apt-get` have conflicting definitions of essential?
2. How do I query all packages that are essential in the sense of `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's from the `Important: yes` field that `init` has (but, e.g., `tzdata` does not).

```
$ dpkg -s init | grep Important
Important: yes
```

The message when trying to remove it is indeed confusing v. `Essential: yes` packages; [Debian bug #826587](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826587) requests a less-confusing message.

PS: You might want to take at look at the Installed-Size. You're not saving much purging `init`, as its purpose is just to make sure that some init system is installed. And if you don't have *an* init system installed, then your system is either a highly customized embedded box or broken.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the answer is was looking for. As a matter of fact, I wanted to find this out in order to explicitly exclude packages like `init` from purging.